# Check if all files in a directory exists elsewhere

Tags: diff, files

I'm about to remove an old backup directory, but before doing so I'd like to make sure that all these files exist in a newer directory.

Is there a tool for this? Or am I best off doing this "manually" using `find`, `md5sum`, sorting, comparing, etc?

---

Clarification:

If I have the following directory listings

```
/path/to/old_backup/dir1/fileA
/path/to/old_backup/dir1/fileB
/path/to/old_backup/dir2/fileC
```

and

```
/path/to/new_backup/dir1/fileA
/path/to/new_backup/dir2/fileB
/path/to/new_backup/dir2/fileD
```

then `fileA` and `fileB` exists in `new_backup` (`fileA` in its original directory, and `fileB` has moved from `dir1` to `dir2`). `fileC` on the other hand is missing in `new_backup` and `fileD` has been created. In this situation I'd like the output to be something like

```
fileC exists in old_backup, but not in new_backup.
```

Comment: You're going to have to hack something up yourself, especially if you want to be able to detect that a file with a different name has the same contents (and thus can be ignored).  It'll only be a few lines, though.

Answer (score 1):

I'd make my own tool. Go the manual route for this one with some fancy find-ings:

```
find /oldbackup -exec basename {} ";" > /tmp/old.txt
find /newbackup -exec basename {} ";" > /tmp/new.txt
for $filename in `cat /tmp/old.txt`
do
    grep $filename /tmp/new.txt
    if [ "$?" -ne "0" ];
    then
       echo "$filename not in new backup"
    fi
done
```

That's incredibly sloppy, but the basic algorithm should be alright. You could also do some catting to figure out which files didn't have copies in both like so:

```
find /oldbackup -exec basename {} ";" > /tmp/old.txt
find /newbackup -exec basename {} ";" > /tmp/new.txt
cat /tmp/old.txt /tmp/new.txt | sort | uniq -c | grep -v 2
```

I can explain the bits and pieces if you need.

Comment: find ... -exec basename {} \; ...

Comment: Genious! I've been doing it the hard way all these years :D

Comment: I should mention that second bit's going to be useless/buggy if the same file names can exist in different folders.

Answer (score 1):

Python has some nice standard library modules for this called dircmp/filecmp.

From Doug Hellmann's PyMOTW, This little bit of code gives you:

```
import filecmp

filecmp.dircmp('example/dir1', 'example/dir2').report()
```

Gives you:

```
diff example/dir1 example/dir2
Only in example/dir1 : ['dir_only_in_dir1', 'file_only_in_dir1']
Only in example/dir2 : ['dir_only_in_dir2', 'file_only_in_dir2']
Identical files : ['common_file', 'not_the_same']
Common subdirectories : ['common_dir']
Common funny cases : ['file_in_dir1']
```

Doug explains the full skinny on filecmp/dircmp way better than I can at:

http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/filecmp/

I like python for things like this because it ports much more easily between Linux/Windows/Solaris for me than anything shell based.

Answer (score 0):

Use diff -uRN dir1 dir2

The diff will be empty if the files are perfect... Or it'll show!

Comment: Aha. Sounds reasonable. (I forgot to write it in the question) but I'd like to ignore file paths :-/

Comment: I didn't get this part.... you just want a 'yes' or 'no' as the output?

Comment: Updated question with an example.